# Add life cycle policy on metricbeat indices

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metrics

I'm trying to add a life cycle policy to my indices through Kibana. I created an index template and a lifecycle policy but I get this error: `setting [index.lifecycle.rollover_alias] for index [jobmetrics-preprod-2022.09.01] is empty or not defined`
Why is that and why do I need to configure an alias for that?
This is the metricbeat.yml ({{}} - We replace depending on the environment).

```
logging.level: error
cloud.id: {{ elastic.cloud.id }}
cloud.auth: {{ elastic.cloud.auth }}
fields:
  class: {{ ec2InstanceClass }}
output.elasticsearch:
    allow_older_versions: true
    indices:
        - index: "jobmetrics-{{ hostenv }}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
setup.template:
    name: "jobmetrics-{{ hostenv }}"
    pattern: "jobmetrics-{{ hostenv }}-*"
    enabled: true
    settings:
      index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

Comment: does https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-error-handling.html#_setting_index_lifecycle_rollover_alias_for_index_y_is_empty_or_not_defined help?

Comment: I did that and I get: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [spark_metrics_LCalias] does not point to index [jobmetrics-preprod-2022.09.08]

Comment: @idanahal were you able to solve this problem? I am facing a similar problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was I didn't remove the "enable rollover" option in the policy configuration.
I didn't want a rollover policy, the lifecycle policy was enough for me but it is still searched for one.
[image]